# Github for windows just deleted all my files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I just tried to do the dutiful thing and backup my work to github, since I had not done a commit in a few weeks due to working on a large work area.

Github for windows notified me it needed to download the latest update and it did so.

I opened the repo, then did a commit.

When I hit sync, it deleted all 138 new files from disk and reset to the last commit more than a month ago.  It also overwrote all existing files that were modified with the old version.

I have no backup... this was meant to be the fscking backup.

Is there some magic git command to undo this shitstorm, or will I need to try recover the new files with a file undelete tool ?

git reflog output:
    40847ec HEAD@{0}: pull --progress --prune: Fast-forward
    913f45e HEAD@{1}: rebase: updating HEAD
    02c93d0 HEAD@{2}: rebase: aborting
    02c93d0 HEAD@{3}: commit:  <-- last good commit

Please help!

Comment: 1. don't panic. You commit isn't lost completely

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke `git reflog`. It should show you the list of recent commits. The you may use `git branch MyHappyBackUp <sha1>` where `<sha1>` is one of those commits from `git reflog`. If you don't have "plain git" installed, try [this build](http://git-scm.com/download/win)

Comment: I haven't dealt with the "github for Windows", and always thought that github is only the hosting for git repos and projects, but I'm sure it's just a shell for plain [old] git for Windows, so you may use it w/o any shell.

Comment: The only output of 'git reflog' is:
40847ec HEAD@{0}: pull --progress --prune: Fast-forward
913f45e HEAD@{1}: rebase: updating HEAD
02c93d0 HEAD@{2}: rebase: aborting
....then the previous commits....

There are no local branches other than 'master'

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is 2 hours later, I just loaded github for windows (again), and my commit is magically there.... still not sync'd though.

WTF ?  Are large commits done asynchronously and then the GUI does not know about them till they are finished or something ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use plain git. It's much more predictive :)