# GitHub: restore old commits

Tags: github

I am working with the GitHub GUI on Windows.

I did some work on my project which was successfully committed about a month ago going forward. Unfortunately other person who also works on this project recently committed the files I changed without realizing that he removed a huge portion of my work.

Now my question would be: is there an easy way of restoring my commits. This is not one commit. For the past month I made several very important commits to the project which got killed by the other party error.

I really don't want to go thru each file individually and re-aaply the changes manually, especially since I already got paid for that work.

How can I get my commits back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you don't see your commit anymore in the history of the repo, that would mean the other developer has done a forced push (`git push --force`).

In that case, use [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23026117/6309)) to find your commits back.

If yo do see your commits, then you could revert ([git revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)) the commits introduced by the other developers in order to cancel them, which should leave your branch in a state reflecting *your* work.

In both cases, this is a communication issue: you need to coordinate with the other developer in order for both of you to agree on a state from which to move forward.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid to hear that responce. Yes, I do see my commits in the log, but there are lots and lots of different commits that our boss and he did in between. I guess the only meaningful answer would be to ask him nicely to put all this back before going any further.

Comment: @Igor true, but you can revert multiple commits in one command though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309