# GitHub for Mac sync deleted my uncommitted changes

Tags: git, github-for-mac

I use GitHub for Mac version 210 on Mac OS X 10.10. Hitting the "sync" button deleted my uncommitted changes. Is that supposed to happen from time to time? I've never had this issue till then, though I've mostly used Github for Windows.

I thought that if I had some uncommitted changes that conflict with whatever there is in the GitHub repository, hitting the "sync" button would fail and yield  the following error message:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

The **Github Desktop** creates an stash with your changes.

You can list the stashes with:

```
git stash list
```

And apply the one that **Github Desktop** created by doing:

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

For more information about `git stash` see [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Comment: This saved my day! they should warn the user before stashing.

Comment: Phew. I was sweating there for a few minutes.

Comment: hahaha I was in your situation and it's not a good thing specially on a Friday...

Comment: Literally almost cried. Lost about 6hours of hard work. TYTYTY!~

Comment: I will buy you a beer. I cannot believe Github Desktop does this. Freaked me out for 24 hours.

Comment: Let me know if you are around Boston. I want that beer!

Comment: Life saver! don't forget to refresh the project to see if your changes are really there!. And merge any conflicts before calling this.

Answer (score 2):

Command line is the way to go. I faced the same situation. When I did a stash list in the Terminal it showed me "GitHub: Stashing to pull in remote changes". And I was able to retrieve my local uncommitted changes back again. :)

Answer (score 1):

It [did happen before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26790666/6309) (even [for GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23026067/6309)).

For added changes to the index,  a `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog` could help ([as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471992/6309))

Comment: Thanks. How comes sync can sometime reset the index to the latest fetched commit?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt not sure (it depends on how sync is implemented). Maybe the new GitHub Desktop (Windows or Mac: https://desktop.github.com/) has fixed this

Comment: Same happened for me, files gone and git fsck doesn't find the deleted files